# Child Div in UL cuts off

Tags: html, css

I have a nested structure where a div contains ul which in turn contains div. My requirement is to have content of most inner div display beyond the width (boundary) of ul or outer div.

```css
    /* Positioning */
    #box1 {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    #box2 {
      position: relative
    }
    #box3 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px
    }
    /* Styling */
    #box1 {
      background: red;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 125px
    }
    #box2 {
      background: blue;
      padding: 2px;
      width: 125px;
      height: 100px
    }
    #box3 {
      background: green;
      padding: 2px;
      width: 500px;
      height: 150px
    }
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <ul id="box2">
    <li>
      <div id="box3" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Refer https://jsfiddle.net/ob641d3s/

**Note:** This was working on Chrome 47 however it stopped working from Chrome 49 onwards on Mac. This is still working on Chrome + Windows

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow: hidden` property on the `#box1` and it's good :)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob641d3s/1/)

Comment: Thanks for response. Your suggestion worked however UL in my page also has overflow-y:auto in order to stop the data from overflowing out of UL.
Due to this property my inner-most div is not able to flow out. If i remove overflow-y property then innermost div displays completely however it also distorts UL display

Comment: What do you mean by "it distorts UL display" ? Can you do a screenshot please ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response everyone,

I was able to find a page that explains the solution very clearly and my problem is resolved following the steps described at following page

https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/